# Spring mvc Joda Datetime converter fail if invalid date

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a domain object that i want to have mapped from JSP that contains a Joda DateTime:

```java
public beanClass{
  private Long id;

  @DateTimeFormat
  private DateTime start;

  getters and setters...
}
```

I have the following converter registered with Spring:

```java
final class StringToJodaDateTimeConverter<S, T> implements Converter<String, DateTime>    {   

  private static final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

  public DateTime convert(String in) {
     try{
        return fmt.parseDateTime(in);
     }catch(Exception e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date");
     }
   }
}
```

Spring obviously hits the converter before my validator class and will populate my error messages with the full error

**Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.joda.time.DateTime for property sampleDate; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "asdf" from type java.lang.String to type org.joda.time.DateTime; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date**

What I want is to get the "Invalid date" message from the exception.

Is there a way to get the exception message "Invalid date" instead of the whole thing to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use file messages.properites to declare specific information:

```
typeMismatch.java.util.Date = Invalid date
```

Of course you should provide information about this file in your spring-context.xml

```
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
     <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/config/messages"/>
     <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>         
    </bean>
```

Comment: how does "typeMismatch.java.util.Date = Invalid date" relate to the date field ?