# Spring MVC- Joda datetime error message for invalid date

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime, jodatime

I have a joda `datetime` attribute in my request object and I have used  `@DateTimeFormat` for the date formatting.
But when I enter an invalid date(say day as 55), it displays the whole message

**Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.joda.time.DateTime for property request.myDate; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "55/12/2014" from type java.lang.String to type org.joda.time.DateTime; nested exception is org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "55/12/2014": Value 55 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,31]**

How can I change it to a custom message as the present message is generated by Spring.

In another SO question
**[Spring mvc Joda Datetime converter fail if invalid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539884/spring-mvc-joda-datetime-converter-fail-if-invalid-date)**
it is asked to make entry in message.properties.
But I'm not able to understand how will it pick the message from property file as I am not doing any `error.rejectValue` type of thing, So how will the message be identified.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539884/spring-mvc-joda-datetime-converter-fail-if-invalid-date but the previous one could not solve my problem

Comment: The approach in the answer you linked to should work, except you need to use key `typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime`. Spring will know to use this message because it will look for `typeMismatch. + fullyQualifiedClassName` message in the configured message source.

Comment: I posted an answer based on the comment and added more detailed information to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you linked to in your question should work. But the message key you should use is for instance `typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime`.

Even though you are not manually rejecting the value anywhere Spring will automatically know where to look for the message based on the rules described in the JavaDoc of  [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html).

In the situation you describe Spring will look for following codes specifically:

1. `typeMismatch.request.myDate` - Conversion message for attribute named "myDate" on an object named "request"
2. `typeMismatch.myDate` - Conversion message for attribute named myDate
3. `typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime` - Conversion message for DateTime type
4. `typeMismatch` - General conversion error message

So you can define some general `typeMismatch` message like *Incorrect format* and then define more specific messages as needed. The more specific error codes have higher priority than those below it. So if you have both `typeMismatch` and `typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime` messages defined, the latter will be used.