# Spring form validation simplify error messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with my form in spring + thymeleaf and I am wondering if there is a way to simplify an error message for date field as when the value is wrong I get this:

[image]

Instead I would like to simply have a text saying: You can't be born yet, or something like that.

Model:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.mm.yyyy")
    @Past
    private Date dob;
```

Form:

```
Date: <input type="date" th:field="*{dob}" />
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dob')}" th:errors="*{dob}"></p>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you use a date picker ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27725232/1291150

Answer (score 2):

First of all your current message is not due to the date being in the future but due to the date  format is wrong and the date cannot be parsed.

Other than that you can customize error messages like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781678/878361

Comment: but why is date format wrong? I do have it set up as dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Look how you are parsing date from string at java backend and check if you are sending date string with same format (eg: dd-MM-yyyy / yyyy-MM-dd etc.) in HTTP request.

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas see this for date format: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/878361

Answer (score 1):

```
@Past(message="You can't be born yet")
```

hopefully this you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Model:

```
 @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date dob;
```

Form:

Add in taglib and dob field in your form

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Add date property

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${dob}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" var="dob"/>
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dob')}" th:errors="*{dob}"></p>
```